# Comma separated string for querying in SSRS

Tags: oracle, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a SSRS report which has a textbox to input values. The user can input single value or multiple values separated by comma.

My report query being called is:

`Select Name, Place from UDetails where BatchNo IN (valuetypedintextbox);`

If a user types A001 then my query returns correct resultset:

`Select Name, Place from UDetails where BatchNo IN ('A001')`

But if they type A001, A002 my query doesnot return correct resultset because it treats text as single string:
`Select Name, Place from UDetails where BatchNo IN ('A001,A002');`

And hence doesnot return any resultset. I want the SSRS report to send below input value, i.e, 'A001','A002'.

The easiest way i can think of is using replace function to replace , with ',' but here i wont be able to add first and last quote '. Has anyone faced similar situation earlier ??

`Select Name, Place from UDetails where BatchNo IN ('A001','A002');`

Answer (score 0):

The Sql statement can be an expression so you could build it from scratch doing something like:

```
="Select Name, Place from UDetails where BatchNo IN ('" & Replace(valuetypedintextbox, ",", "','") & "');"
```

Comment: My SSRS report doesnot allow me to write enter this query.

Comment: You need the query to be in Text mode

Answer (score 0):

I would go to the Dataset Properties, Parameters pane.  I would edit the Parameter Value for that Parameter and set it to something like:

= Split ( @valuetypedintextbox , "," )